# This из функции не ссылается на глобальный объект

Tags: javascript

```js
'use strict';

    window.color = 'blue';

    function getColor() {
        return this.color;
    }

    console.log(getColor());
```

Почему this из функции не ссылается на глобальный объект?

Answer (score 0):

`this` ссылается на глобальный объект в функциях, вызванных не как методы, только в нестрогом режиме. В строгом режиме в таких случаях `this` является `undefined`.

См., например, http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch07.html#_this_is_undefined_in_nonmethod_functions

Можете удалить или закомментировать `'use strict';` и убедиться в изменениях поведения.

Answer (score 0):

Контекст выполнения функции — это одно из фундаментальных понятий в JavaScript. Контекстом еще часто называют значение переменной this внутри функции. Также иногда путают понятия «контекст выполнения» и «область видимости»

Каждый вызов функции имеет и область видимости, и переменную this, и контекст выполнения. Область видимости определяет доступ к переменным при вызове функции и является уникальной для каждого вызова. Значение переменной this — это ссылка на объект, который «вызывает» код в данный момент. Контекст выполнения содержит и область видимости, и аргументы функции, и переменную this.

Когда мы вызываем функцию как функцию (не как метод объекта), эта функция будет выполнена в глобальном контексте. Значением переменной this в данном случае будет ссылка на глобальный объект. Однако, если функция вызывается как функция в строгом режиме (strict mode) — значением this будет undefined.